# Why rudin said that if any two of the sets $E_n$ have elements in common, then these will appear more than once in the above sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

I have some confusion in rudin book real analysis

My doubt is given below[image]

**My doubts** : Rudin said that if any two of the sets $E_n$ have elements in common, these will appear more than once in (17).

I'm  thinking that

[image]

$E_1=  x_{11}$

$E_2= x_{21} ,x_{12}$

$E_3= x_{31},x_{22} , x_{13}$

............so on

But  here $E_1 \cap E_2\cap \ldots\cap E_n= \emptyset$

There is no any common element in  any two set of $E_n$

I don't understand  why rudin said that if any two of the sets $E_n$ have elements in common,then  these will appear more than once in the above sequence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E_1\cap E_2\cap\ldots\cap E_n=\emptyset$ does not imply $E_i\cap E_j=\emptyset$ for every $i\neq j$. Take $E_1=\{1,2\},E_2=\{1,3\},E_3=\{2,3\}$ for example.

So if there is some element $x$ in two different sets $E_i$, $E_j$, we have that $x$ is numbered as both $x_{ik}$ for some $k$ and as $x_{jl}$ for some $l$, so it will appear at least twice in the given sequence ("at least" because it could be in a third different set).

Comment: thanks u @Darsen    that mean $x_{11} , x_{22}$..  need  not be distincts    .I was thinking that  $x_{11}, x_{22}$ must be distinct